Beg for Sapolia testnet tokens
I want to start to learn solidity and need some Sapolia testnet tokens. Anybody can send me any? Thanks a lot!
Here is my address: 0x38CA4Fe15f55118B4403a3BB77be944592A9e37F

Mate , you can always get SEPOLIA ETH tokens through public faucets , you just have to connect your wallet and request for the testnet tokens.
Here is the link to public faucet provided by chainLink https://faucets.chain.link/sepolia
If that doesn't work here is the link where you can find public faucets https://faucetlink.to/sepolia
These are just Testnet tokens, so it doesnt have any real value like the mainnet ETH , but it is essential in the development and testing of Smart Contracts.
